# Grails 3 deployment not working

Tags: ubuntu, grails, spring-boot, tomcat8

Project works perfectly in local environment .When i deployed project in server no error occurred .But can't access any page due to o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter .
here is error log .

```
    08-May-2017 10:27:23.220 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /var/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.43/webapps/bimbley.war
08-May-2017 10:27:29.494 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

08-May-2017 10:27:53.157 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /var/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.43/webapps/bimbley.war has finished in 29,936 ms
08-May-2017 10:27:53.158 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.43/webapps/docs
08-May-2017 10:27:53.198 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.43/webapps/docs has finished in 40 ms
08-May-2017 10:27:53.199 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.43/webapps/manager
08-May-2017 10:27:53.247 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.43/webapps/manager has finished in 48 ms
08-May-2017 10:27:53.250 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.43/webapps/examples
08-May-2017 10:27:53.500 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.43/webapps/examples has finished in 250 ms
08-May-2017 10:27:53.501 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.43/webapps/ROOT
08-May-2017 10:27:53.527 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.43/webapps/ROOT has finished in 21 ms
08-May-2017 10:27:53.528 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.43/webapps/host-manager
08-May-2017 10:27:53.563 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.43/webapps/host-manager has finished in 35 ms
08-May-2017 10:27:53.573 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-May-2017 10:27:53.589 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
08-May-2017 10:27:53.594 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 30441 ms
2017-05-08 10:28:26.832 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter     : Forwarding to error page from request [/] due to exception [Could not resolve view with name '/home/index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet']

javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/home/index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
```

Here is my application.yml file config

-

```
--
grails:
    profile: web
    codegen:
        defaultPackage: bimbley
    spring:
        transactionManagement:
            proxies: false
info:
    app:
        name: '@info.app.name@'
        version: '@info.app.version@'
        grailsVersion: '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
spring:
    main:
        banner-mode: "off"
    groovy:
        template:
            check-template-location: false

# Spring Actuator Endpoints are Disabled by Default
endpoints:
    enabled: false
    jmx:
        enabled: true

---
grails:
    mime:
        disable:
            accept:
                header:
                    userAgents:
                        - Gecko
                        - WebKit
                        - Presto
                        - Trident
        types:
            all: '*/*'
            atom: application/atom+xml
            css: text/css
            csv: text/csv
            form: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            html:
              - text/html
              - application/xhtml+xml
            js: text/javascript
            json:
              - application/json
              - text/json
            multipartForm: multipart/form-data
            pdf: application/pdf
            rss: application/rss+xml
            text: text/plain
            hal:
              - application/hal+json
              - application/hal+xml
            xml:
              - text/xml
              - application/xml
    urlmapping:
        cache:
            maxsize: 1000
    controllers:
        defaultScope: singleton
        upload:
            maxFileSize: 2000000
            maxRequestSize: 2000000
    converters:
        encoding: UTF-8
    views:
        default:
            codec: html
        gsp:
            encoding: UTF-8
            htmlcodec: xml
            codecs:
                expression: html
                scriptlets: html
                taglib: none
                staticparts: none
    gorm:
        # Whether to autowire entities.
        # Disabled by default for performance reasons.
        autowire: true

    mail:
        host: "smtp.gmail.com"
        port: 465
        username: "XXXXX@gmail.com"
        password: "XXXXXXX"
        props:
            mail.smtp.auth: "true"
            mail.smtp.socketFactory.port: "465"
            mail.smtp.socketFactory.class: "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"
            mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback: "false"

endpoints:
    jmx:
        unique-names: true

---
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: true
        use_query_cache: false
        region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory

dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
   #driverClassName: org.h2.Driver



grails:
    mongodb:
       host: "localhost"
       port: 27017
       username: ""
       password: ""
       databaseName: "bimbleydb"

environments:
    development:
        grails:
            serverURL: http://localhost:8080
            mongodb:
                connectionString: "mongodb://localhost:27017/bimbleydb"
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/bimbleydb
            username: root
            password:

           # url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    production:
        grails:
            serverURL: http://45.79.83.127:8080
            mongodb:
                connectionString: "mongodb://localhost:27017/bimbleydb"
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/bimbleydb
            username: root
            password: XXXXXXX
            #url: jdbc:h2:./prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

Comment: What version of Grails? Are you starting tomcat from the project directory?

Comment: grails version 3.2.3 .I build war first then deploy it tomcat 8 .Just copy war to /tomcat8/webapps folder.Also i add provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat" in build.gradle.

Comment: right so what directory are you in when you start tomcat?

Comment: I am trying deploy in Ubuntu server.Which is production server and i build war for production .I installed tomcat 8 in Ubuntu and I start tomcat by running this script /tomcat8/bin/startup.sh .I don't understand its spring security issue or something else .

Comment: Check your `HomeController` have `def index = {}` and your folder `views` contains folder named `home` with `index.gsp` file

Comment: Because its running successfully in local so their is no such issue .I solved it .We should place war file in /opt/tomcat/webapps .Tomcat should be placed in opt folder .Thanks anyway.